# Extending sidebar down page

Tags: css, xhtml

I am trying to get my right sidebar to fill to extend the full length of the content within my #wrapper on this site: http://www.starmedianetwork.com/

I put a red border around it to try to see where my #right is on my page. I have tried working with:

height:100% on that #right and others. Also searched on google about clear fixes but I couldn't get that too work, also came across some solutions on experts-exchange, but those didnt work.

Any ideas how I can get my sidebar to extend with the background-color to fit the length?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this approach: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlayouts/

Comment: how is this not helpful? The link contains a solution to the problem. You can see it working here: 

http://www.alistapart.com/d/multicolumnlayouts/2ColFixedRightContentTallest.html

Comment: It doesn't extend to the bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a faux sidebar:

```
<div class="sidebar_back"><.div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <p>The sidebar content</p>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
.sidebar_back {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 200px;
  background: #444; // the color you want the sidebar to be
  position: absolute;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

The `.sidebar_back` will extend all the way to the bottom of the page, so just give that the color that you'd like the sidebar to be, and the actual sidebar div will appear to be full-height. You can use a percentage-based width instead of pixels too. Here's a codepen showing an example:
http://codepen.io/poopsplat/full/jquBv

Comment: Thanks man that helped me out with a very similar problem I was having, too. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a div to fill the height of it's parent.  It may work in one browser, but I've had this problem and it is not simply solved by a height:100%.

You can simulate the background by creating a background that tiles all the way down the side.  This isn't the most elegant solution.

The only other solution I have found is to use javascript.  After the page loads, you can set the height of the div to precisely what it needs to be based upon the height of the div that you want it to expand within.

There may be some javascript libraries out there to assist you with positioning of this troublesome div, but I can't conjure up one at the moment.

Comment: Give the parent a height (however you like), and `position: relative`; then specify the child with a `position: absolute` (and top: and bottom: of 0) and it can fill it's parent's height. It's not necessarily pretty though..

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but...it feels like it should work (which of course is likely the kiss of death to the attempt):

```
#wrapper
    {position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffa;
        }

#right {position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 15%; /*  this has to be fixed-size so you can account
            for it in the next bit; but can still be kinda
            fluid-ish... */
    display: block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
        }

#left   {width: 83%; /*  100 - (15% + 2% (for a gutter)) */
    margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 16%; /*   less than 100 - 83, to allow for rounding of % or px */
    display: block;
    background-color: #0ff;
    overflow: auto;
        }

p   {display: block;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
        }
```

...

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="left">
            <p>The left-hand content</p>

        </div>

        <div id="right">
            <p>The right-hand content</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

It's not terribly pretty, but it does work. Though I'm not a fan of using `position: absolute` (or `fixed`) so if anyone's got a better suggestion I'd go for it =)

Incidentally, there's working demo of the implementation (with added 'lorem ipsum' goodness) over at: http://www.davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/cols.html.

(Okay, I lied: I clearly *have* tried it now...)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I have found to solve this issue:

You have to use four div tags - one main container which contains the sidebar, the main content, and a footer.

First, add and style the elements in your stylesheet:

```
#container {
width: 100%;
background: #FFFAF0;
}

.content {
width: 950px;
float: right;
padding: 10px;
background: #FFFAF0;
}

.sidebar {
width: 220px;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
background: #FFFAF0;
}

#footer {
clear:both;
background:#FFFAF0;
}
```

You can edit the different elements however you want to, just be sure you dont change the footer property "clear:both" - this is very important to leave in.

Then, simply set up your web page like this:

```
<div id=”container”>
<div class=”sidebar”></div>
<div class=”content”></div>
<div id=”footer”></div>
</div>
```

I wrote a more in-depth blog post about this at [http://blog.thelibzter.com/how-to-make-a-sidebar-extend-the-entire-height-of-its-container][1]. Please let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my sidebar problem for my admin page using jQuery with just a couple of lines of code

```
$('aside').height($(window).height()-($('#header').height()+$('#secondary_bar').height())-2); // Extend sidebar to bottom of viewport
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('aside').height($(window).height()-($('#header').height()+$('#secondary_bar').height())-2); //change size of bar when viewport height changes
    $('#main').height($(window).height()-($('#header').height()+$('#secondary_bar').height())-2); //change size of main content when size of viewport changes
});
```

It seems to work in all browsers, however, when the content on the right is larger then the viewport and issue will occur when you scroll down.  It can be fixed with some content height checks but for me it doesn't matter.  Hope that helps someone out there =)