# How do I make a <hr /> tag go vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a `<hr />` tag go vertically, instead of its standard appearance as a horizontal line/going sideways?

I'd like to be able to use this on a mobile site, so a more widely-supported solution is preferable to one that only works in the latest browsers.

Comment: what do you mean 'go down instead of up'

Comment: you mean a vertical line instead of a horizontal line?

Comment: html spec defines hr as a down tag, if you want it to go up, use the `<rh>` tag /just kidding

Comment: sorry misspelling, fixed

Comment: just put a border on the left side of the content you want the vertical line.

Comment: My answer in contingent upon the idea that you just need your `<hr>` up and down.  What do you intend to do with a vertical `<hr>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will require changes to more than just the hr. the element above and below it must be floated. the effect can be achieved with a solid border:

```
<div class="section1"> content </div> 
<div class="section2"> more content </div>
```

CSS:

```
.section1 {  
    float: left; 
    width: 200px; 
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

.section2 { 
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
}
```

Edit: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860448/vertical-line-spacer-between-two-divs)

Answer (score 1):

You could use css transforms.  However, this just turns it, things are still where they would be if you hadn't rotated it.

**HTML**

```
<hr/>
<hr class="vert" />
<hr id="vert1" />
```

**CSS**

```
/*All <hr>*/
hr {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}
/*<hr> of class ".vert"*/
 hr.vert {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
/*<hr> with id "vert1"*/
 hr#vert1 {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Would that transform all or only 1? Also would it work on firefox? Also i noticed the <hr> automatically goes to the center.....

Comment: might as well just use a border-left style on some element than do a transform of a hr.

Comment: probably not what he wanted but useful/interesting anyway +1

Comment: @Luiz187 Added code for all, some, and one vertical `<hr>`

Comment: So something like
`#Vertical-line {width:2px; height:200px; border-left: 2px solid #000}`

Answer (score 1):

Well you could possibly make a `div` (`<div></div>`) and then give it values with css later regarding height/width. If you want it to apply to one specific object give it an `id` `<div id="">` and more than one object give it a `class` `<div class="">`

An example of the css you'd do is:

```
#(id name) or div.(class name) {
height: ; (how tall) 
width: ; (how wide you want it) 
background-color: ; (sets the color of the bar) 
position: ; (depends on if you want it absolute or static etc.) }
```

You can obviously add/remove other css as you go depending on what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could re-style `<hr />` as an inline-block element, with specified height...

```
hr {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 256px;
}
```

That's just a basic example to get the `<hr />` to look like I think you want it to look. You'd have to play with height and width (and possibly positioning) to make it do exactly what you need...

Comment: For what it's worth, @Eru has the technique I'd probably use in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a div:

```
<div style="border-right:1px solid #333;">
Content here
</div>
```

This is with inline css. Otherwise, separate the css:

```
div {
border-right:1px solid #333;
}
```